# Byte manipulation in PHP

Tags: php, byte

In PHP, if you have a variable with binary data, how do you get specific bytes from the data?  For example, if I have some data that is 30 bytes long how do I get the first 8 bytes?

Right now, I'm treating it like a string, using the `substr()` function:

```
$data = //...
$first8Bytes = substr($data, 0, 8);
```

**Is it safe to use `substr` with binary data?**

Or are there other functions that I should be using?

Comment: You mean if it is binary data?

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally all string functions in PHP are safe to use with raw bytes. The issue that mostly crops up are null-bytes, but only for filesystem-functions: http://php.net/manual/en/security.filesystem.nullbytes.php

Your `substr()` is perfectly fine to use with binary strings. Some other functions like `strtok` and `ereg` however interface to C, where the "\0" character becomes an issue.

Comment: Thanks, the only string function I'm using this with is `substr`.  What if PHP is configured to use UTF-16 for its strings where each character is > 1 byte?

Comment: @MichaelAngstadt. I would consider that a misconfiguration and not care. For what it's worth `mb_substr("\0\0\0\0", 0, 2)` seems to work for UTF-8. For UTF-16 however it returns twice the size, as expected. So what's more likely to fail is your followup processing under these conditions.

Comment: Oh, so `substr` will ALWAYS assume 1 character to be 1 byte, while `mb_substr` takes into account the character encoding?  Sounds like I'd be safe using `substr` no matter the character encoding.

Comment: @MichaelAngstadt. I though you were referring to the horrible [mbstring overloading feature](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php), where substr indeed behaves as mb_substr. No, if it's disabled, then yes, `substr` in PHP5 will treat all strings as 8-bit char chains. (PHP6 might not.)

Comment: Just stumbled upon an issue: Carriage Return character gives trouble: reading a bit sequence of `00001101` with substr() returns a `00000001`. [Ideone](http://ideone.com/UfM2QG).

Comment: @Serge `0b00001101` doesn't amount to a carraige return. It represents integer `13`. That's a string of two bytes `1` and `3`. And only `1` is left after slicing out the first.

Answer (score 15):

If the [mbstring extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) is installed and [mbstring overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php) is enabled, then using `substr` might give you trouble.  Mbstring overloading will cause `mb_substr` to be automatically called every time `substr` is called (if mbstring is installed and mbstring overloading is *disabled*, then `substr` will correctly retrieve the bytes).  The following code will use `mb_substr` if mbstring is installed and `substr` if it isn't.  The "8bit" character encoding is used, which will treat each character as 1 byte and will ignore null terminators ('\0').

```
if (function_exists('mb_substr')) {
    $bytes = mb_substr($string, 0, 8, '8bit');
} else {
    $bytes = substr($string, 0, 8);
}
```

[Thanks to ircmaxell](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/228004#228004)

Comment: Please can you clarify what you mean by "will ignore null terminators". This would be a deal breaker for data manipulation if it were true.  I have made some tests and I cannot see it ignoring \0 characters. (Edit) oh i just read the chat.  You mean over "ascii". So using "8bit" **doesn't** ignore null terminators.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds good since PHP is dealing strings (internally)  "like" C char * (1byte=1char)

On the other side, it could be broken if the string is in Unicode encoding 
(2 bytes = 1 character)

nb: You can also play with pack() and unpack() to manipulate "real" bytes

Comment: @Stef Thanks, yeah, that's one thing I was worried about...what if PHP is configured to support something like UTF-16 for its strings?

Comment: @Michael: I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: Yes me too, but who knows may be in 2011 the famous php 6.0 ;)

Comment: @BoltClock You mean PHP doesn't support UTF-16?

Comment: @Michael: There is the multi-byte extension, but that means Unicode support isn't built into PHP core. They're trying to work this out for PHP 6. Sad, I know.

Comment: @BoltClock Gotcha, so as long as we don't use this extension, 1 character == 1 byte.

Comment: PHP6 is unlikely to happen in 2011. Most of the core 6 features were pulled forward into 5.3, a bunch more are being pulled forward into 5.4. Unicode support is not one of the items.. the lead guys on it lost steam.