# Set Byte Array Position To Arbitrary Integer Value

Tags: php

I'm implementing an AES encryption algorithm, and I need to come up with a way to increment my iv. I'm stuck on a pretty simple question:

If I have a 16-byte, randomly generated array, how can I set a specific byte to an arbitrary value?

For example, say that I just want to arbitarily set my least-significant byte to 0xff:

```
<?php

$bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
echo bin2hex($bytes) . "<br>";

$bytes[15] = 0xff; // arbitrarily set this byte
echo bin2hex($bytes) . "<br>";

?>
```

This yields output like this (clearly wrong):

> 9299dd089611fa47f130c4e92aaa09dc
>   9299dd089611fa47f130c4e92aaa0932

I'm trying to get to this output:

> 9299dd089611fa47f130c4e92aaa09ff

I've been at this for hours, and I just can't figure it out. Can anyone help? Thank you.

EDIT: I've also tried to output the array like this:
`echo var_dump(unpack('C*', $bytes));`

This yields output like this (these numbers won't cross reference to what you see above, but just focus on the last byte):

> array(16) { [1]=> int(242) [2]=> int(106) [3]=> int(88) [4]=> int(109)
>   [5]=> int(145) [6]=> int(251) [7]=> int(38) [8]=> int(54) [9]=>
>   int(39) [10]=> int(61) [11]=> int(175) [12]=> int(183) [13]=> int(27)
>   [14]=> int(98) [15]=> int(13) [16]=> int(106) } 
>   array(16) {
>   [1]=> int(242) [2]=> int(106) [3]=> int(88) [4]=> int(109) [5]=>
>   int(145) [6]=> int(251) [7]=> int(38) [8]=> int(54) [9]=> int(39)
>   [10]=> int(61) [11]=> int(175) [12]=> int(183) [13]=> int(27) [14]=>
>   int(98) [15]=> int(13) [16]=> int(50) }

Shouldn't the last byte show

> [16]=> int(255)

Comment: And your expected output would be?

Comment: 9299dd089611fa47f130c4e92aaa09ff

Comment: The "another attempt" has a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry about that. fixed.

Comment: @Tarik - that gives me the same output as `$bytes[15] = 0xff`

Comment: decbin(255) returns a string, so it's obviously incorrect. $bytes[15] = 0xff; should work though.

Comment: Well, the output is as I show it. 32 is a hexadecimal representation of 0xff, so I understand the translation. What I don't understand is why the bin2hex function outputs this way after I set that byte while it clearly outputs otherwise when I use the openssl_random_pseudo_bytes function initially to set the same byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use string manipulation routines to manipulate raw byte arrays. See [Byte manipulation in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570812/byte-manipulation-in-php)

Try:

```
$bytes = substr_replace ($bytes, chr(0xFF), 15 , 1);
```

Also try:

```
$bytes[15] =  chr(0xff)
```

Comment: So it was a matter of converting the integer to a character.