# AES-256 in PHP and securely storing keys?

Tags: php, encryption, aes

I have the following code...

```
   $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
   $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
   $key = pack("H*", "Insert64CharacterStringHere");

   $value = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $value, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

   $value = $iv . ":" . $value;
```

I'm using this to encrypt data in AES-256 on my site. I store the initialization vector with the data being encrypted, and between the data and the initialization vector is a colon so that I can explode the string later into the initialization vector and the data, then decrypt.

What I'm wondering about is where to store the key. If I store it on the same database, it's almost as insecure as simply leaving the data unencrypted. I have a feeling leaving the key lying around somewhere in my PHP code is just as insecure.

Where should the key be stored? Is this an appropriate way to store the initialization vector? Am I safe using the colon as a deliminator? I.E. will the initialization vector or the data ever contain a colon?

Comment: Unless you want someone to be physically present to type in a passphrase every time a decryption happens you're going to have to store the key *somewhere* on the server in plain text. You can put layers of obfuscation between the application and the key, but the fact remains that the decryption will need the plaintext key at some point. Them's the breaks.

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer...

> Is this an appropriate way to store the initialization vector? Am I safe using the colon as a deliminator? I.E. will the initialization vector or the data ever contain a colon?

The IV is always 16 bytes for AES (in CBC mode). There is no need to have a delimiter. You can safely use the `substr()` function to split the IV and the ciphertext before decryption:

```
$iv = substr($encrypted, 0, 16);
$ct = substr($encrypted, 16);
```

If you're in a multibyte string environment, you should use `mb_substr() like this`:

```
$iv = mb_substr($encrypted, 0, 16, '8bit');
$ct = mb_substr($encrypted, 16, mb_strlen($encrypted, '8bit'), '8bit');
```

In fact, since the IV is randomly generated, it may contain a colon at some point in time. Expected value is 1 for every 16 encryptions. It doesn't matter whether the data contains a colon, since you're probably searching from the beginning.

Comment: Not for exploding, then the string gets split around each colon, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes That nicht be the case, but you would still need to deduce which colon is the right one if there are multiple and implode the other ones. It's just not worth it.

Comment: I'm of course not arguing in favour of the use of a colon, Artjom. I'm just making a small point about "since you are probably searching from the beginning" but [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) by default does split around each delimiter. So without setting the `limit` you may also split around colons in the data.

Comment: I suggest checking that mbstring.func_overload is not overloading your substr function as it could break your decryption if your server decides to treat your binary string as a multibyte string.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ Interesting! It seems that `mb_substr()` with the 8bit option would nearly work when overloading is enabled, but it ignores `\0`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4598270 Is there a working way to achieve this in an mb environment? Is it worth its own question?

Comment: @Artjom B. Ah that is unfortunate. I guess because it considers it a string and not data. Well substr should work in an mb environment if you are using the proper mb functions rather than the "lazy" function overloading way. I read somewhere that it is or will be deprecated soon so i would just check the php configuration variables and give an error if it's on. It's a long shot but what about changing the config vars in code to temporarily disable mb function overloading?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I tested using mb_substr with the 8bit option on a string made up of hex2bin("3334003536") which contains \0.  Strangely I could not get it to ignore the data. PHP 5.6.3 on windows. Is there any credible reference to it breaking with \0 characters?